# Graphite /Grafana : how to migrate from version 2.0.2 to version 3.1

Tags: graphite, grafana

me again ..

Now new project to come.. need to migrate the graphite/grafana to new version.. currently i used version 2.0.2 but the latest we have 3.1.. I would like to migrate to that new version.

I had done some researches and i found from the graphite site only as per link:http://docs.grafana.org/installation/migrating_to2/ .. but it does look like importing the new database and new dashboard to me..

BG: my current version 2.0.2 still use Carbon as database.

Answer (score 0):

You do not need any migration, just upgrade Grafana and everything should work as before. Dashboards are backwards compatible

Comment: ohh i found it from this link https://github.com/grafana/grafana/issues/3382.. let me try :)